# Best Practices for SharedPreferences

Tags: android, model, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

A set of questions about `SharedPreferences` that I was looking for:

- What, Why, When?
- How does it work inside?
- The Best Practice to use it?

Only some of those question were answered here. That's why I made some investigations, and tests.

As I've answered on my own question I've decided to share answer with other people.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've wrote a little article that can also be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

### Best Practice: SharedPreferences

Android provides many ways of storing application data. One of those ways leads us to the **SharedPreferences** object which is used to store private primitive data in key-value pairs.

All logic are based only on three simple classes:

- [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)
- [SharedPreferences.Editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)
- [SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html)

#### SharedPreferences

`SharedPreferences` is main of them. It's responsible for getting (parsing) stored data, provides interface for getting `Editor` object and interfaces for adding and removing `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`

- To create `SharedPreferences` you will need `Context` object (can be an application `Context`)
- `getSharedPreferences` method parses Preference file and creates `Map` object for it
- You can create it in few modes provided by Context, it's strongly recommended to use MODE_PRIVATE because creating world-readable/writable files is very dangerous, and likely to cause security holes in applications

  ```
  // parse Preference file
  SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  // get values from Map
  preferences.getBoolean("key", defaultValue)
  preferences.get..("key", defaultValue)

  // you can get all Map but be careful you must not modify the collection returned by this
  // method, or alter any of its contents.
  Map<String, ?> all = preferences.getAll();

  // get Editor object
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

  //add on Change Listener
  preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(mListener);

  //remove on Change Listener
  preferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(mListener);

  // listener example
  SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener mOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
      = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    }
  };
  ```

#### Editor

`SharedPreferences.Editor` is an Interface used for modifying values in a `SharedPreferences` object. All changes you make in an editor are batched, and not copied back to the original `SharedPreferences` until you call commit() or apply()

- Use simple interface to put values in `Editor`
- Save values synchronous with `commit()` or asynchronous with `apply` which is faster. In fact of using different threads using `commit()` is safer. Thats why I prefer to use **`commit()`**.
- Remove single value with `remove()` or clear all values with `clear()`

  ```
  // get Editor object
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

  // put values in editor
  editor.putBoolean("key", value);
  editor.put..("key", value);

  // remove single value by key
  editor.remove("key");

  // remove all values
  editor.clear();

  // commit your putted values to the SharedPreferences object synchronously
  // returns true if success
  boolean result = editor.commit();

  // do the same as commit() but asynchronously (faster but not safely)
  // returns nothing
  editor.apply();
  ```

#### Performance & Tips

- `SharedPreferences` is a [Singleton](http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html) object so you can easily get as many references as you want, it opens file only when you call `getSharedPreferences` first time, or create only one reference for it.

  ```
  // There are 1000 String values in preferences

  SharedPreferences first = context.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  // call time = 4 milliseconds

  SharedPreferences second = context.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  // call time = 0 milliseconds

  SharedPreferences third = context.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  // call time = 0 milliseconds
  ```
- As `SharedPreferences` is a [Singleton](http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html) object you can change any of It's instances and not be scared that their data will be different

  ```
  first.edit().putInt("key",15).commit();

  int firstValue = first.getInt("key",0)); // firstValue is 15
  int secondValue = second.getInt("key",0)); // secondValue is also 15
  ```
- When you call `get` method first time it parses value by key and adds this value to the map. So for second call it just gets it from map, without parsing.

  ```
  first.getString("key", null)
  // call time = 147 milliseconds

  first.getString("key", null)
  // call time = 0 milliseconds

  second.getString("key", null)
  // call time = 0 milliseconds

  third.getString("key", null)
  // call time = 0 milliseconds
  ```
- Remember the larger the Preference object is the longer `get`, `commit`, `apply`, `remove` and `clear` operations will be. So it's highly recommended to separate your data in different small objects.
- Your Preferences **will not be removed** after Application update. So there are cases when you need to create some migration scheme. For example you have Application that parse local JSON in start of application, to do this only after first start you decided to save boolean flag `wasLocalDataLoaded`. After some time you updated that JSON and released new application version. Users will update their applications but they will not load new JSON because they already done it in first application version.

  ```
  public class MigrationManager {
   private final static String KEY_PREFERENCES_VERSION = "key_preferences_version";
   private final static int PREFERENCES_VERSION = 2;

   public static void migrate(Context context) {
       SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       checkPreferences(preferences);
   }

   private static void checkPreferences(SharedPreferences thePreferences) {
       final double oldVersion = thePreferences.getInt(KEY_PREFERENCES_VERSION, 1);

       if (oldVersion < PREFERENCES_VERSION) {
           final SharedPreferences.Editor edit = thePreferences.edit();
           edit.clear();
           edit.putInt(KEY_PREFERENCES_VERSION, currentVersion);
           edit.commit();
       }
   }
  }
  ```
- `SharedPreferences` are stored in an xml file in the app data folder

  ```
  // yours preferences
  /data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PREFS_NAME.xml

  // default preferences
  /data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_preferences.xml
  ```

[Android guide.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

#### Sample Code

```
public class PreferencesManager {

    private static final String PREF_NAME = "com.example.app.PREF_NAME";
    private static final String KEY_VALUE = "com.example.app.KEY_VALUE";

    private static PreferencesManager sInstance;
    private final SharedPreferences mPref;

    private PreferencesManager(Context context) {
        mPref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public static synchronized void initializeInstance(Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new PreferencesManager(context);
        }
    }

    public static synchronized PreferencesManager getInstance() {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(PreferencesManager.class.getSimpleName() +
                    " is not initialized, call initializeInstance(..) method first.");
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    public void setValue(long value) {
        mPref.edit()
                .putLong(KEY_VALUE, value)
                .commit();
    }

    public long getValue() {
        return mPref.getLong(KEY_VALUE, 0);
    }

    public void remove(String key) {
        mPref.edit()
                .remove(key)
                .commit();
    }

    public boolean clear() {
        return mPref.edit()
                .clear()
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yakiv has mentioned everything about preferences so neatly and nicely. I just want to add one more point. While editing data in shared preferences we usually do

```
mPref.edit()
```

which creates a new object of SharedPreferences.Editor type every time which can result in unnecessary objects in memory. So you can maintain a reference to editor object too and save memory and object creation time and corresponding garbage collection time.